# $_SESSION lost on AJAX request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, session

I've got a Smarty project which works with jQuery as well, where I struggled about an issue some days ago.
   **index.php**

```
  session_start();
  require_once 'controller.php';

 *//nothing else happens here*
```

I load my controllers and templates then

**controller.php**

```
<?php
    isset($_GET[controller]) ? $controller="/".$_GET[controller] : $controller = "/index";
    isset($_GET[department]) ? $department="/".$_GET[department] : $department = "/index";

   require_once "controller".$department.$controller.".php";
   $smarty->display("templates" . $department . $controller . ".tpl");
```

on page load my jQuery auto loads different sub-templates and I've echoed the `$_SESSION` content at the beginning of each controller file

Here's my JS

```
autoload_subtemplate = function(data) {

var target    = data.target;
var id        = data.id;

*//fill target container*
var page2load = data.page.split("_");

$.get("http://"+GLOB_ENV+"MYDOMAIN/"+page2load[0]+"/"+page2load[1]+"?"
  + "import=1"
  + "&data=" + JSON.stringify(data),function(content){

    $("#"+target).html(content);

    *//searching for content to autoload*

    if( $('#'+target).parent().attr("id")=="content" ){

      $("a.auto.loadsubtpl").each(function(){

        var load = $(this).attr("loadtarget");
        var page = $(this).attr("loadpage").split("_");

       //****************************************************
       //the file, loading now, returns an empty $_SESSION
       //NOTE: it's the same action, as the $.get some lines above
       //where the SESSION is NOT lost!!!
       //****************************************************
        $.get("http://"+GLOB_ENV+"MYDOMAIN/"+page[0]+"/"+page[1]
          +"?import=1"
          +"&data=" + JSON.stringify(data),function(details){

          $("#"+load).append(details);
          $(this).addClass("active");
          $("#"+load).show();
        });
      });
    }
  }
);
return false;
};
```

Now the weird thing: If I put an `echo "whatever";` into my `root/index.php`, right after the `session_start();` the `$_SESSION` is still there.

As this workaround is kinda stupid i'm wondering if there is someone out there, who has a explanation for this.

I simply call `print_r($_SESSION)` in the regarding php files, i'm loading via AJAX.

Comment: You haven't fully explained the problem? Where is the code showing you calling session variables?

Comment: it's a simple print_r($_SESSION); in the called ajax files

Comment: maybe, i should specify it better .... the FIRST $.get doesn't loose the session, only the SECOND does.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you haven't called `session_start()` on your Ajax page

Comment: the index.php used with tha AJAX is excatly the same file, which has session_start() within :/

Comment: What does a var_dump($_SESSION) get you on those pages?

Comment: correct values on the initial calls and the first $.get call .... emptyness at the second $.get